# On subtraction numeric data is becoming character type in R programming and incorrect answer on subtracting decimal

Tags: r, character, numeric, subtraction

```
probablity = runif(50,0,1)
price = numeric(0)
for(i in 1:50){
  price[i] = sum(1.0,probablity[i])
}

class(probablity[i])
class(1.0-probablity[i])
```

[image]

Difference between two numeric should be numeric

1-0.2094 should return 0.701

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior. Does this happen in a fresh R session if you copy/paste exactly what you've posted? What version of R are you using?

Comment: `class(1.0-probablity[i])` gives me `[1] "numeric"`.

Comment: what is the answer? 1.0-probablity[i]

Comment: Running `set.seed(123)` before your code, `1.0-probablity[i]` gives me `[1] 0.1421723`

Comment: I was just giving an example taking 0.2094. I also think the problem is with this R version. What should I do? My R version is 4.2.1

Comment: What version are you using

Comment: @anjali This is weird, what does `get('-')` return?

Comment: I downgraded my R version to R 4.0.1, deleted R 4.2.1 files from ProgramFile and then re-installed. Now it is working perfectly fine